# GitKraken Push Failed

Tags: git, git-bash, gitkraken

When I push with **gitkraken** I get error messages such as :

> Failed to write chunk header. The connection with the server was
>   abruptly terminated

or

> Failed to write final chunk. The connection with the server abruptly
>   terminated.

or

> Failed to write chunk footer. The connection with the server abruptly
>   terminated.

However if I use the git bash console, push works fine and within gitkraken pull and fetch work fine.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is connection VPN. An example ; you can pull or fetch the project correctly. But you can't push the local project. 
You must configured local VPN settings.

Finally; you must see the project files in the git-->log-->HEAD 
Configure the URL adress.

http://pserver.lan//xyz.project/git  or
http://192.0.15.1//xyz.project/git